# Format date with 'nd' or 'th' after the day number in Access

Tags: database, date, ms-access, format, ms-access-2007

I'm printing menu cards for events in an Access 2007 report want the event date at the bottom of the print out formatted in the following way: 2nd December, 2013 (or 25th December, 2013)

Is there a way that I can format the date field in the Access database so that it prints out that way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the VBA `Format` function doesn't provide the capability you want.  However you could use a custom VBA function to format the day part of the event date and add on the formatted month and year.

```vb
DayString([event date]) & " " & Format([event date], "mmmm, yyyy")
```

Save this function in a standard module.

```vb
Public Function DayString(ByVal pDate As Date) As String
    Dim intDay As Integer
    Dim strReturn As String

    intDay = Day(pDate)
    Select Case intDay
    Case 1, 21, 31
        strReturn = intDay & "st"
    Case 2, 22
        strReturn = intDay & "nd"
    Case 3, 23
        strReturn = intDay & "rd"
    Case Else
        strReturn = intDay & "th"
    End Select
    DayString = strReturn
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, HansUp. I have added the public function, but am unsure how to get it working. On my event procedure I have: Private Sub cmdMenu_Click()DoCmd.OpenReport "rptEventCourse", acViewPreview, , "[tblEventCourse]![EventID]=" & Forms.frmEventDetail.ID End Sub Would I call DayString somewhere in there?  And where would I add: DayString([event date]) & " " & Format([event date], "mmmm, yyyy") ?

Comment: I didn't know where your event date comes from, so I pretended you have something available named `[event date]`.  As to where you use it, you can add a text box to the report footer and use this as its Control Source property: `=DayString([event date]) & " " & Format([event date], "mmmm, yyyy")`

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you so much.  Sorry, as you can see, new to this site.  Do I need to rate this answer, say I'm very happy or something like that?  (Sounding very dim now...)

Comment: The general policy is that you can accept the answer which you find most useful ... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  After you accumulate 15 reputation points, you can also rate questions and answers by voting them up or down.